# Proving a Parallelogram using Vectors and Midpoints

Tags: geometry, vectors

In a quadrilateral OABC, O is the origin and a,b,c are the position vectors of points A,B and C. P is the midpoint of OA, Q is the midpoint of AB, R is the midpoint of BC and S is the midpoint of OC.

I have already showed that PQ = 0.5b, but I'm not sure how you use that information to prove that the quadrilateral is a parallelogram. If you could offer any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly you can show that $\overrightarrow{SR} = 0.5\bf b$. Then $\overrightarrow{PQ} = \overrightarrow{SR}$, so they have the same direction and magnitude.

Use that to show $PQRS$ is a parallelogram.